# MIPS A String to Integer Conversion

Tags: string, mips

Basically, I will read a string from console, which is no problem. The first and third characters in this string will be a 0-9 number and I want these numbers to store as ıntegers in memory  to reuse later. I get "Exception occured at PC=0x0040004c" and when clicking abort I get "Unaligned address in store:0x100100c9".

What is the problem? Please, help!

EDIT:When I run step by step, error occurs in line 24.

```
.data

exp:    .space 201     #allocate 200 bytes for logic expression to be read from stdin. +1 is for null char.
dimension:  .space 8   #allocate 8 bytes for dimensions of environment

.text


main: 

li  $v0, 8             # load appropriate system call code into register $v0;
                       # code for reading string is 8
la  $a0, exp           # load address of string to be read into $a0
li  $a1, 201           # load length of string to be read into $a1
syscall                # call operating system to perform read operation


la $t0, exp
la $t1, dimension

add $t2,$zero,$zero

lb $t2, 0($t0)
addi $t2, $t2, -48
sw $t2, 0($t1)




li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to align the data at word boundary when storing a word.

For that you would have to use `.align` directive with parameter `2`.

In your example dimension is not aligned because exp is 201 bytes length (not a multiple of 4). So you would have to use:

```
.data

exp:    .space 201     #allocate 200 bytes for logic expression to be read from stdin. +1 is for null char.
.align 2   # Align data
dimension:  .space 8   #allocate 8 bytes for dimensions of environment

.text
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved! Although I have made some research on web on this .align topic, I still cannot figure out why this error happened. By the way, why not .align 4 but 2?

Comment: @mualloc: it is a restriction of the mips architecture. The instruction that performs a `lw`/`sw` requires that the word to be read/written be at a word-boundary (i.e. the address be a multiple of 4)